# Complexity of solving a polynomial equation

Tags: time-complexity, polynomials

Given a polynomial equation of degree `n` with `m` variables, that is guaranteed to have at least one solution, what is would be the Big O notation of the least complex algorithm to find a solution?

Comment: You may find this useful: http://mate.dm.uba.ar/~visita16/cimpa/notes/Sabia.pdf

Comment: I believe the efficiency of the algorithm would be O(n^m) if you are recursively looking at the algorithm m times, and most efficiently O(m). I'm unsure of your experience in Big O notation however, khan academy and other similar sites have some sites that may be able to help with what you are looking for.
[https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-science/algorithms/asymptotic-notation/a/big-o-notation](https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-science/algorithms/asymptotic-notation/a/big-o-notation)

Comment: There's an entire book on this subject: https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-319-16721-3

Comment: This question is actually tricky, mostly because there is no defined nth degree polynomial solving formulas and because there are multiple ways of solving algorithmically polynomials. I asked this question mostly because I am not able to answer it as my training in calculus is clearly lacking and I'd miss any shortcut that would lead to a lower complexity